# Wrong Order of Output in C++

Tags: c++

I am writing a deamonizing program.Its working fine but does not produce any output in the file mentioned. Is the program I wrote for deamonizing correct? Also , this program produces the output in reverse order.Can anybody explain why?

output:

```
Closing File descriptors
Child Created.Exiting Parent
```

program :

```
int main(void)
{

    pid_t pid, sid;
    int i=0;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (pid > 0)
    {
            cout<<"Child Created.Exiting Parent\n";
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    umask(0);
    sid = setsid();
    if (sid < 0)
    {
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if ((chdir("/home/csgrad/suryakum/checking")) < 0)
    {
          cout<<"Directory not changed\n";
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    cout<<"Closing File descriptors\n";
    close(STDIN_FILENO);
    close(STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(STDERR_FILENO);
    while (1)
    {
            i++;
            ofstream outputFile("program3data.txt");
            outputFile<< "Run "<<i<<"\n";
            sleep(30); /* wait 30 seconds */
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: The file program3data.txt is created but with nothing in it.

Comment: The order of output is non-deterministic since there is no coordination between the two processes.

Comment: Presumably you want to put the line : ofstream outputFile("program3data.txt"); outside the loop?

Comment: C does not have `cout`.  This should be tagged C++ only, as it is not `C`

Comment: you gotta close the output file to get the output written to it. If you want to 'tail' it then you need to flush it

Answer (score 1):

one of the basic thing in file handling that you are missing here is whenever we will  open a stream  to write in a file  we must have to close that stream.
add the follwing line  after writing to the file .

```
outputFile.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of `ofstream outputFile("program3data.txt");` should occur outside the `while`.

> Also , this program produces the output in reverse order.

The order is indeterminate, execution after the `fork()` occurs in parallel.